# 2000/2010s SF trilogy about a technokinetic kid taken by authorities to fight far-away battles

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a trilogy of sci fi novels in high school that I really want to read again. I know the first book started with "V".

The story was about a kid that was living with his dad, had some technokinesis ability that he used to help his dad win gambling. He was taken in by authorities and put into a program where he fought space battles with machines controlled through quantum entanglement, over territory. His love interest fought against him for the Chinese, and had burn scars on her face.

Comment: I meant technomancy, had telekinesis in the back of my mind. Turns out I was thinking of a different story though, I've been reading it and he's just really good at games

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the *Insignia* trilogy by S. J. Kincaid; first book was released in 2012. The book starting with a V would be the second one, *Vortex*.

[image: covers for Insignia trilogy]

From [HarperCollins](https://www.harpercollins.com/9780062132772/insignia/):

> More than anything, Tom Raines wants to be important, though his shadowy life is anything but that. For years, **Tom’s drifted from casino to casino with his unlucky gambler of a dad, gaming for their survival**. Keeping a roof over their heads depends on a careful combination of skill, luck, con artistry, and staying invisible.
>
> Then one day, Tom stops being invisible. Someone’s been watching his virtual-reality prowess, and he’s offered the incredible—**a place at the Pentagonal Spire, an elite military academy**. There, Tom’s instincts for combat will be put to the test and if he passes, he’ll become a member of the Intrasolar Forces, helping to lead his country to victory in World War III. Finally, he’ll be someone important: a superhuman war machine with the tech skills that every virtual-reality warrior dreams of. Life at the Spire holds everything that Tom’s always wanted—friends, the possibility of a girlfriend, and a life where his every action matters—but what will it cost him?

More precisely...

**He was taken in by authorities and put into a program where he fought far-away battles with machines controlled through quantum entanglement.**

Basically a ripoff of *Ender Game*, the kids were trained to control machines via proxy which were doing the dirty job for them.

**His love interest fought against him for the Chinese.**

Tom is part of the american faction and works to take down the Russo-Chinese alliance.

---

Plagiarising my own answer to [Series about proxy space battles via implanted computers in kids](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/197657/98028)

Comment: Yes!! Thanks very much, buying them on Amazon immediately 